# Build failure for Scala, Maven and Java integration

Tags: java, scala, maven, jenkins

I am actually developing a plugin for Jenkins, and I want to integrate Scala, Java and Maven in my plugin. I developed part of my plugin in Java and I would like to develop other parts in Scala. 
The thing is when I integrate all of them (maven, Scala, and Java), I get this error from the scala maven plugin :

```
    [INFO] artifact org.kohsuke.stapler:stapler: checking for updates from scala
[INFO] D:\workspace\remote-deployment-new\src\main\java:-1: info: compiling
[INFO] D:\workspace\remote-deployment-new\target\generated-sources\localizer:-1: info: compiling
[INFO] Compiling 4 source files to D:\workspace\remote-deployment-new\target\classes at 1352200897840
[ERROR] D:\workspace\remote-deployment-new\src\main\java\com\ebiznext\plugins\RemoteDeployment.java:33: error: RemoteDep
loyment is already defined as package RemoteDeployment
[INFO] public class RemoteDeployment extends Plugin implements Action, ExtensionPoint, Describable<RemoteDeployment> {
[INFO]              ^
[ERROR] one error found
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 52.801s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Nov 06 12:21:39 CET 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 27M/370M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.1.0:compile (default) on project remote-deploymen
t-new: wrap: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1(Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I totally understand the error  saying that the class `RemoteDeployment` is already defined as a package. It's true, because when developing a plugin for Jenkins, if I have a class, for instance `RemoteDeployment` defined in the package com.ebiznext.plugins, I have to create a package `com.ebiznext.plugins.RemoteDeployment` under `src/main/resources`. That's a jenkins convention, I cannot do anything about it.

How can I correct this problem?

Here is my POM :

```
<project>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.466</version><!-- which version of Jenkins is this plugin built 
        against? -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.ebiznext.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>remote-deployment-new</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<name>Remote Deployment</name>
<packaging>hpi</packaging>
    ....         
    <build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>test-compile</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Comment: I have the same problem. I have a mixed Java / Scala project. For my test classes, I have the test data in resources, e.g. for com.organization.foo.bar.MyTest the data is in src/test/java/resources/com/organization/foo/bar/MyTest. Everything was fine until I switched one of the tests from Java to Scala, then it will not compile, reporting the "is already defined as package" error. It must be a clash between the resource name and the class name.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using the net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin to do your compilation. You can then set the argument to the compiler `-Yresolve-term-conflict:object`.

For example:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <recompileMode>incremental</recompileMode>   <!-- NOTE: incremental compilation although faster requires passing to MAVEN_OPTS="-XX:MaxPermSize=128m" -->
        <useZincServer>true</useZincServer>          <!-- NOTE: if you have Zinc server installed and running, you can get faster compilation by enabling this -->
        <!-- addScalacArgs>-feature</addScalacArgs -->
        <args>
            <arg>-Yresolve-term-conflict:object</arg>   <!-- required for package/object name conflict in Jenkins jar -->
        </args>
        <javacArgs>
            <javacArg>-Xlint:unchecked</javacArg>
            <javacArg>-Xlint:deprecation</javacArg>
        </javacArgs>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>scala-compile-first</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>add-source</goal>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>scala-test-compile</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

For an example, see here: https://github.com/adamretter/jenkins-scala-plugin/blob/master/jenkins-scala-plugin-executer/pom.xml#L57

Answer (score 0):

If your java code dependent on scala class, you should compile scala class first.

this works:

`clean scala:compile compile package`